# Does sorting happens using distinct clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the below

```
empname salary
a   10000
b   5000
c   5000
```

If I do `select distinct salary from @t`

the output being

```
salary
5000
10000
```

It has been sorted ... Why so?

Comment: Good question! Whatever the answer is, though, the SQL standard doesn't guarantee ordering for **any** operation unless you're specifying `ORDER BY`. So even if a side-effect is a sorted result set you **should not** rely on it.

Comment: I don't know the internals of SQL Server, but some RDBMS do `distinct` with _hashing_ not _sorting_, at least in some cases.

Answer (score 7):

Given that without an explicit `ORDER BY` the order of returned rows is undefined; the `DISTICT` probably causes a [`distinct-sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177486.aspx) (look at the plan) operation which is probably why they are ordered in your example.

Comment: As @Alex has written, only by checking plan you will be sure what happens

Answer (score 0):

actually in this case no order guarateed, because of different optimization algorythms of sql-server engine

Comment: Not true - it could be reordered from PK or insert order by other factors such as join types in the background

Comment: No, this is nowhere near guaranteed - it is a common myth that people keep perpetuating. If you don't specify an ORDER BY clause, SQL Server will deem it is free to return rows in whatever order is most efficient. Sometimes this is PK or insert order, but sometimes it is not. If people read your first sentence only (which I did the first time I read the answer) they will certainly get the wrong impression about assumptions they can make about SQL Server behavior.