# Using distinct clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, using distinct clause is always doing an implicit order by or I need to specify an order by for that? I want to be sure that using distinct put data in order.

Here you have an example, distinct is doing order by

```
create table #MyTable (id int)

insert into #MyTable values (3)
insert into #MyTable values (2)
insert into #MyTable values (8)

select distinct id from #MyTable
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does sorting happens using distinct clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547412/does-sorting-happens-using-distinct-clause)

Comment: SQL Server can use a hash for the `DISTINCT` in which case the results will almost certainly not be in the desired order. e.g. `CREATE TABLE T(X INT);INSERT INTO T SELECT number%2 FROM master..spt_values;SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T` gives results `0,1,-1` for me.

Answer (score 5):

Although the typical implementation of `distinct` is done using some kind of ordered data structure, the order it uses may not be the one you need.

There are:

- No guarantees that the data will be ordered any which way
- No guarantees that the same query on the same data later/tomorrow will return the data in the same (arbitrary) order
- No guarantees that the observed ordering will be consistent

The `distinct` clause does not imply ordering. As such, if you need the data ordered in a particular manner, you **have to** add an `order by` clause to the query.

Also note that one of the data structures that can be used is a hashtable/hashset, and though these may produce data that looks ordered if there are only a few values placed into them, with larger quantities this will break down, and **regardless, this is implementation specific and undocumented**. Do not rely on any such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

**DISTINCT** clause has nothing to do with ordering records. You have to explicitly use **ORDER BY** clause for sorting.

```
select distinct id 
from #MyTable
Order By id
```

Comment: Even if your example happens to be sorted, you cannot depend on it.  If you want it ordered you must use ORDER BY.